# Using iTunes store client data for authenticating users in iPhone App

Tags: ios, objective-c, payment-processing

I know that the iTunes Store stores client information, such as the client name and credit card information. Eg, if you want to buy a game, you have to log in using your apple account and provide credit card details. These details are already stored with Apple

I want to build an app that uses this credit card information stored with Apple to allow clients to make payments. Note: I do not want to use the in-app purchase model.

Does Apple provide an API that given the client username and password, allows me to access the credit card information and then make payments?

The idea is to build a charity donation app around this. But the in-app model does not support this.

In a nutshell, we basically want to use the existing iTunes infrastructure to build a charity donation app. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh good god no. This would be such a huge security risk if Apple did allow it. I would rethink you design.

Comment: why not? And what are my alternatives?